# Token Access Issue

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging, nft

Hi Sir we Create Token but we cloud'n have full access on Tokens. Like we create 2000M Token but when I add it in my Metamask I got only 200M Tokens. Cloud you please me out for this?

Comment: I've edited my answer to add a note. The contract doesn't have a mechanism to increase an existing account balance. Once deployed contract cannot be modified and only existing methods can be used. In this case it is not possible to alter balances. The only solution in this case is to migrate to a new contract.

Answer (score 0):

Check where and how much you minted tokens.
Note: it's better to attach the token address for more info.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/42964)

Comment: @Ismael And what could be the answer to such a question? This is all that can be answered with such input data. The rest is just guesswork...

Comment: Sorry, but I see it more as a comment than an answer. But the question itself is quite incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

In the source code from [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/address/0x9388f54fa978aa9e24395a8b69033304eccea4df#code) you can see that total supply and initial balance are not assigbed the same value.

```
function Bitscoin(
    ) {
    balances[msg.sender] = 2000000000000;               // Give the creator all initial tokens (100000 for example)
    totalSupply = 20000000000000;                        // Update total supply (100000 for example)
    name = "Bitscoin";                                   // Set the name for display purposes
    decimals = 4;                            // Amount of decimals for display purposes
    symbol = "BTCX";                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
}
```

The difference is a zero.

- `balances    = 2000000000000`
- `totalSupply = 20000000000000`

So 90% of the total supply is unassigned.

Note: The contract doesn't have a mechanism to increase an existing account balance.